# Visibility of progress bar in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple circular loading bar in html css which is hidden at the start. On click, I call a javascript function that iterates and send ajax call on server. I'm trying to set visibility to true before the loop. And one it is completed, I need to again set the visibility of false. 
Here is my code:

```
<div class="sk-fading-circle" style="visibility: hidden" id="loading">
    <div class="sk-circle1 sk-circle"></div>
    <div class="sk-circle2 sk-circle"></div>
    <div class="sk-circle3 sk-circle"></div>
    <div class="sk-circle4 sk-circle"></div>
    <div class="sk-circle5 sk-circle"></div>
    <div class="sk-circle6 sk-circle"></div>
    <div class="sk-circle7 sk-circle"></div>
    <div class="sk-circle8 sk-circle"></div>
    <div class="sk-circle9 sk-circle"></div>
    <div class="sk-circle10 sk-circle"></div>
    <div class="sk-circle11 sk-circle"></div>
    <div class="sk-circle12 sk-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Here goes the javascript:

```
function visible(id, flag){
    if (flag == 1){
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else if (flag == 0){
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

function sendRequest(urls) {

    if (urls.length == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        var A = urls.split(',');
        visible('loading', 1);
        for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var result_set = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    if (result_set.flag == 1) {
                        visible('stock-table', 1);
                        insertRow('stock-table', result_set.url, result_set.title);
                    }
                }

            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "scrapper.php?url=" + A[i], true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        visible('loading', 0);

    }

}
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: please add working code snippet for us to check what the problem is. Use codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: *Hint:* don't use flags where you can just use a boolean value. It only makes it more complicated.

Comment: @NasirT will this work? https://jsfiddle.net/Le885m44/

Comment: I think @Aloso answered your question below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that an `XMLHttpRequest` is **asynchronous**. This means that javascript doesn't wait while the request is sent to the server. This is what happens:

1. The progress bar is set to "visible"
2. Several `XMLHttpRequest`s are started
3. The progress bar is set to "hidden"
4. The responses of the `XMLHttpRequest`s are received after some time.

Obviously, **step 3 and 4 should be exchanged**. But here's a solution for this: Every time an `XMLHttpRequest` is started, **increase a counter**. Every time the response is received, decrease it. Then check if the counter is 0. If it is 0, all resources are loaded and the animation can be hidden.

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Thank you @Aloso